# Map multiple sources to singular file definition which may change

Tags: java, file, mapping, translation

I have multiple datasources (of varying types) providing information on incoming orders. Instead of processing these all differently, it would be much easier and less error-prone to convert these to a universal format and process orders in that format.

So, say, I get orders sent to me by Company A in a CSV format with their own naming conventions, Company B in a TXT file with different naming conventions and format, etc.. I would like to take these files and translate them all to a singular format.

What would be the best way to approach this?

I know it would be easy to write a direct mapping from each individual incoming file to the outgoing file, but there must be a better approach. If the output ever changes then all of those mappings must be rewritten.

Example files:

Company A:

```
ID,SKU,QTY
1,NM-44,4
2,NM-99,1
```

Company B:

```
SKU,QTY,Name
TM-60,5,Marissa
```

Output for A:

```
Order ID,SKU,Quantity,Name
1,NM-44,4,
2,NM-99,1,
```

Output B:

```
Order ID,SKU,Quantity,Name
,TM-60,5,Marissa
```

Comment: an example of various inputs and the ONE expected output would be helpful

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz added

Comment: how come you have 2 different output files? why don't you use a single file?

Comment: i think writing an individual mapper for each input file type is the only solution in this case

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz because presumably these files would be translated at different times.

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz Both output files use the same unified format.

Comment: Why is the “output” file format necessary at all?  Why not keep the orders in memory as `Collection<Order>` objects?

Comment: @VGR right, since they are the same unified format, why not use a single file for all outputs? then append new files to the existing single output file? just trying to wrap my head around why there has to be a separate output file for each input file.

Comment: what is the purpose for an output file @user2827048?? do you just read it in again to create your internal data structure???

Comment: the only reason I see to have another file get generated for each different file type is if you are using an entirely different program (parser) to parse the input files which generates the output files, and another program which processes the output file with the orders?? otherwise have a parser class, extend the parser for each different file format and have them add to a common internal data structure of say HashMap<Company, ArrayList<Order>> allOrders?

Comment: @RAZ_Muh_Taz Yes, the idea was to have two separate programs. Since these are two totally different processes (translating the files, and processing the orders) I think it would be simpler and easier to maintain two separate programs rather than one large program.

Comment: then if you change the output file format, you'll have to change the program reading those files as well...